# In Ubuntu 20.04, wifi connection does not automatically connect on startup

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and unfortunately there appears to be a very annoying issue with the network manager. The connection that should happen automatically on startup does not initiate automatically. Every time I start the computer, I have to manually select the network I want to connect to. This issue did not happen in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and is extremely annoying. I made sure the connection is available to all users and set to automatically connect with priority 0, and deleted the connection and tried again but nothing seems to work. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think this worked for some reason: go to 'Network Connections', select the gear to edit the connection, go to the 'Wi-Fi Security' tab, and in the 'Password' box, select 'Store the password only for this user'. Save, restart, and bam it connects automatically. Strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience  with Lubuntu 20.04 on a Acer chromebook c710 with a hidden network.
I solved by

```
sudo featherpad /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/"name of your ssid".nmconnection
```

system-connections
and add just under

```
[wifi]
hidden=true
```

Comment: Sorry made a mistake the sudo command should be:

sudo featherpad /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/"name of your ssid".nmconnection and add just under [wifi] hidden=true

Answer (score 0):

You can set the suitable network with higher priority, this can be done

1, `nm-connection-editor > your prefered network > general > priority > 10`

larger number means bigger priority

if your computer is stuck with some corrupted network, you can delete them, or make them with negative priority

2, Equivalently, you can edit with

`sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/yournetwork.nmconnection`

and change the line to
`autoconnect-priority=10`